# SQL Database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I am fairly new to using SQL so sorry if this is a simple question.  I have a program that I'm writing that generates and fills a database.  I would like to see what was generated so I'm trying to open the database in VS.

I can go to the server explorer and click 'Connect to Database' which gives me the ability to browse to the .mdf file.  When I do it opens and I can see the table definitions, etc.  All is good so far.

However if I go back into my program and press the 'Clear Tables' button that I created it says it has run through fine but nothing changes in my VS view.  I know that it did actually clear out the tables because when I re-run the 'Build Database' command it looks for each table and doesn't find it (so it creates it).

However as I said in the IDE through all of this I see the original database, nothing cleared out or recreated.  I have tried right clicking and hitting 'Refresh' on the database, disconnecting and reconnecting, and nothing seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you need to look at the DB, don't bother doing thru VS, get SQL managment Studio up and running to that.

Comment: +1 to Limey. You may need to download the express (free) version of SQL Server and there's an option screen to just install the tools, which will be Management Studio. It's a GUI for managing SQL databases. You may already have it - I'm pretty sure VS installs SQL, I'm just not sure if the tools go with it.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is the better way to go, but, until you set that up, you should be able to look at the data in the table with just Visual Studio. When you bring up Database Explorer and right-click on a table, you should see an option that says "Show Table Data". Try that option to see the contents of the table.

Comment: I can see the data in the table, the problem is that it doesn't seem to be updating even when I know that the database is being updated.  It's like VS remembers the initial state and never changes it.  Looking into Management Studio...

Comment: In Visual Studio if you have a txt file resource and you set it's copy property as "Copy Always", it will be copied to build path all build operation and replaced old modified txt resource file. Your problem looks similar and you are talking about mdf file. Do you create your database on server, or access it on file system?